# Docker compose: Composing React Error: Could not find required file

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I'm trying to dockerize a React app while doing so I encounter an error suggesting I don't have any index.html file

this is my dockerfile:

```
# 1. For build React app
FROM node:lts AS development

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# 
COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json

# Same as npm install
RUN npm ci

COPY . /app/

ENV CI=true
ENV PORT=3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

FROM development AS build

RUN npm run build
```

this is my docker compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

and this is my working directory:

[image]

and this is the error I recieve:

```
[+] Building 9.4s (15/19)                                                          
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                          0.3s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 750B                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                             0.2s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:alpine               4.6s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:lts                   4.2s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                   0.0s
 => [auth] library/nginx:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                  0.0s
 => [development 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:lts@sha256:59eb4e9d6a344ae  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-2 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:alpine@sha256:a74534e7  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                             0.2s
 => => transferring context: 3.19kB                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [development 2/6] WORKDIR /app                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [development 3/6] COPY package.json /app/package.json              0.0s
 => CACHED [development 4/6] COPY package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json    0.0s
 => CACHED [development 5/6] RUN npm ci                                       0.0s
 => [development 6/6] COPY . .                                                1.4s
 => ERROR [build 1/1] RUN npm run build                                       2.6s
------
 > [build 1/1] RUN npm run build:
#0 0.902 
#0 0.902 > frontt@0.1.0 build
#0 0.902 > react-scripts build
#0 0.902 
#0 1.823 Could not find a required file.
#0 1.824   Name: index.html
#0 1.824   Searched in: /app/public
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build]: exit code: 1
```

I have used Awesome-compose examples to write these config files so I think they might be best practices that are out there.

Comment: The error message suggests you're missing a specific file (`./public/index.html`); does it exist?  Can you `npm run build` without involving Docker in the process?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering, "Could not find a required file. Name: index.html," indicates that your build process for the React app is unable to locate the index.html file in the /app/public directory. This file is a crucial part of a React app, as it serves as the entry point for your application.

To fix this issue, you need to ensure that your React app's public directory and the index.html file are correctly included in your Docker build context. Here's how you can do that:

Verify your project structure:

1. Make sure your React app project structure includes a public
   directory, and inside that directory, there should be an index.html
   file. This file is the entry point of your React app.
2. Update your Dockerfile to copy the public directory into the Docker
   image: Modify your Dockerfile as follows to include the public
   directory:

   ## 1. For build React app

   FROM node:lts AS development

   ## Set working directory

   WORKDIR /app

   ## Copy package.json and package-lock.json

   COPY package.json /app/package.json
   COPY package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json

   ## Same as npm install

   RUN npm ci

   ## Copy the entire project (including the 'public' directory)

   COPY . /app/

   ENV CI=true
   ENV PORT=3000

   CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

   ## (No need for the second 'FROM' directive)
3. Ensure your Docker Compose configuration includes the 'public'
   directory in the build context: Update your Docker Compose file like
   this:

   version: "3.9"
   services:
   frontend:
   build:
   context: .  # This refers to the current directory, including the 'public' directory
   container_name: frontend
   ports:
   - "80:80"

By following these steps, you should be able to include the public directory in your Docker image and resolve the "index.html" file not found issue during the build process. Make sure your project structure is correct, and the public directory is located in the root of your project, containing the required index.html file.